# Left and Right Handed Traffic

Tags: geographics, entity

How can I generate a `Geo` plot similar to the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-_and_right-hand_traffic) page about left- and right-handed traffic.

**Question**

A direct way would be to make a list of countries that follow L/R traffic handedness and plot. I was wondering if there a way to get this information from the `Entity` system?

[image]

Attribution (link doesn't work): By Benjamin D. Esham (bdesham) - This W3C-unspecified vector image was created with Inkscape ., Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2653447

Comment: Download the `.csv` file from [`here`](https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/countries-that-drive-on-the-left) and import it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```mma
countries = StringTrim[StringReplace[
    Select[StringSplit[StringReplace[
       Import[
        "https://www.worldstandards.eu/cars/list-of-left-driving-countries/", 
        "HTML"], "\r" -> "\n"], "\n"], StringEndsQ[#1, "drives on the left"] & ], 
    {" drives on the left" -> "", RegularExpression["\\([^)]*\\)"] -> ""}]]
interpreter = Interpreter["Country"]
lefties = Sort[Union[Select[interpreter /@ countries,  !FailureQ[#1] & ]]]
all = interpreter /@ CountryData[]
righties = Select[all,  !MemberQ[lefties, #1] & ]
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm[None], FaceForm[Red], (Polygon[#1, "Polygon"] & ) /@ 
    righties, Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Alaska", "UnitedStates"}][
    "Polygon"], FaceForm[Blue], (Polygon[#1, "FullCoordinates"] & ) /@ lefties}, 
  GeoBackground -> "CountryBorders", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The reason for the special treatment of United States of America Alaska state is because it is missing from the map of the USA in the country data.

Comment: The line of code "righties = Select[all,  !MemberQ[lefties, #1] & ]" can be replaced by the line "righties = Complement[all, lefties]".